# df output issues

Tags: perl, shell

```
$df_ret = `ssh -q rajesh 'df -hP'`;

print "The value is $df_ret";   

if ($df_ret =~ /\/boot/) 
{
    print "The value is $df_ret";
}
```

Expected result:

```
/dev/sda1               126931     39530     80848  33% /boot
```

But, it's coming whole `df -k` output. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is matching against the whole output as one string. You probably want to split it into lines, first and then match each line:

```
my @df_ret = `ssh -q rajesh 'df -hP'`;

foreach my $line (@df_ret) {
    if ($line =~ m! /boot$!)
    {
        print "The value is $line";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using the shell:

```
ssh -q rajesh 'df -hP' | grep /boot
```

Comment: +1 if the OP is using perl just to process the output, and not using ssh within the scope of a larger perl script.